# Is there a way to join two strips in VSE?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Is there a way to join two strips into one? For example, If you cut a strip in two, do some other stuff and then realize, you want to undo the cut or something; I found how to groups strips, but not how to actually merge them into one.

Comment: Could be scripted. If the two pieces are on same channel and the media and ends match, no probs. (not really joining, would change end points of active one  and delete the other.)

Comment: I  sometimes make a duplicate of an uncut strip, keep that as a spare, hide it (hotkey H) or move it out of way. With the original strip, I split strips with either hotkey K for soft cut or Ctrl K for hard cut. This video tutorial is little OLD, but still useful for learning distinctions between soft cut & hard cut. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pw-GPKEMNxY

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For strip split by *Cut* <kbd>K</kbd> - *Erase* <kbd>X</kbd> second part of strip and extend the end point manually or by *Snap to Playhead* <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

[image]

For strip split by *Hold Cut* <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> go to properties panel <kbd>N</kbd> and change *Hold Offset End* to zero (or what ever number that fits to a gap).

[image]

Comment: I did a "hard cut" or whatever its called, so I don't think I can extend the strip as it (shouldn't?) have that data anymore. Let me know if that is a misunderstanding. And yes, it doesn't seem to cause problems to just link them end-to-end and not worry about it, I just like to have "clean" workspaces when possible.

Comment: I didn't write the question, I just posted the bounty

Comment: @hatinacat2000 With the hard cut (Ctrl K), you can drag the first/last frozen frame out further if you like. I learned that from this OLD tutorial (still useful). It teaches the distinction between hard cut (Ctrl K) and soft cut (K).  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pw-GPKEMNxY

Comment: @hatinacat2000 The edit addresses all of your concerns, correct?

Answer (score 1):

I found that you can simply render multiple strips together then drag and drop that rendered strip back into blender.

I wanted to transform multiple cut strips at once (blender doesn't let you do that), so rendered them into a single strip.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for a separate option as it's automatic. First, upload a movie strip. Then add another and put it  where the first one ends. Render under a selected name and extention. Done.

Comment: I don't think he speaks about two different video files to be merge into one, rather that joining one with cut.

Comment: And is there a difference? A cut piece can be renamed/indexed if that's what you mean.

Comment: He wants to just organise strips (operation in a few seconds), your solution with rendering can take hours.

Comment: @vklidu: aky-her wants the cut pieces back into one strip. In Blender I found no such option and if you know any other way than mine... External, in it online editors, are an alternative.

Comment: Solution was described in an Answer.