# Movie editing in 2.8- how to recombine previously cut strips back into one strip

Tags: modifiers, interface, video-sequence-editor

After cutting a strip, how do I recombine the cut strips?

I can move them together using move <kbd>G</kbd>  and Snap <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> , but that simply butts them together (at the handles), it doesn't make them back into a single unique strip for purposes of using modifiers- the software still considers them separate strips and evidently strip modifiers (like color balance) can't be applied across multiple strips.

I'm talking about times when it would be impractical to simply use the history editor (undo, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> ).

I guess my question is applicable to anytime I might want to treat adjoining strips as one unique strip for the purposes of applying strip modifiers, is that correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to join two strips in VSE?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/151023/is-there-a-way-to-join-two-strips-in-vse)

Comment: Oh.... after working with that more I see that it does seem to work... I had read that through before and somehow didn't understand or read it correctly, but now that you mention it I re-studied it and yes it does seem to work the way I want. So I guess I need to play with it a little more to understand the difference between cut and hold-cut, which would be a different question. Thanks!

Comment: To answer the second part of my question, I found out about the "Copy to Selected Strips" button.